# Is there a way to access socket.io events like "onConnection" within a router url Node.js + express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have an index.js file which serves to setup the entire backend application I want. Sets up express server and routing and socket imports.

I'm trying to call a socket event within one of my routes files. "localhost:8080/yt/youtube1" would go from my index.js file->yt calls my youtube.js file -> youtube1 calls 'router.get("youtube1").

Side Note: If anyone has any tips for cleaning up my server creations/imports with express and whatnot I would appreciate it. I don't fully understand how that all works

```
//index.js file
const express = require("express"); //import express
const app = express(); //express server
const http = require("http");
const server = http.createServer(app);
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const PORT = 8080;

const cors = require("cors"); //install cors

const io = new Server(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: "http://localhost:3000",
        methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    },
});

const loginroute = require("./routes/auth"); //import routing from routes/login
const youtubeRoutes = require("./routes/youtube")(io);
```

```
//youtube.js file

const express = require("express");

// Creating express Router
const router = express.Router();

var returnRouter = function (io) {
    console.log("test(first call from youtubeRoute)");
    router.get("/youtube1", (req, res) => {
        console.log("test2");
        io.on("connection", (socket) => {
            console.log(`User Connected: ${socket.id}`);
        });
        res.send("This is the youtube HOME request");
    });

    router.post("/message", function (req, res) {
        console.log("Post request hit.");
        //listen to a 'pause' message from client->emit a pause message to client
        io.on("pause", (socket) => {
            socket.emit("userPaused");
        });

        res.send("test post request");
    });

    return router;
};
```

Comment: the `io.on` handlers should not be placed inside your express route handlers but instead on their own else you are just stacking up io handlers, what you do is place `io` inside express using `app.set('io', io)`, then its available inside `req.app.get('io')`, then depending on how you track connections, you would do the same for connected clients `app.set('socket_clients', socket_clients)` and `req.app.get('socket_clients')` which you add and remove items inside the io handlers connection, disconnected etc i.e `socket_clients[socket.id] = {user_id: 123, ABC: 123}`

Comment: So if I understand correctly I do `app.set('io',io)`, and then just do routing the same but access io in my youtube.js like "`req.app.get('io')`. 

I don't fully understand how I would access the io events then inside my youtube.js file.

like `const myIO = req.app.get('io')
router.get("youtube1",(req,res) =>{
    myIO.on("connection", (socket) => { });

}`?

Comment: why do you need to access the io events from express? you should only ever need emit to some connected client from express for some reason like you want to trigger it via a HTTP call, i.e like you posted some data and want to emit the update via the socket to one or more users etc.

Comment: I suppose I don't I was just trying to do it as an extra layer of organization. But you bring up a good point. I think I outta just do the socket io events outside of my router functions. Thank you for your help Lawrence! :)